# Why is $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A})=\text{tr}(\sqrt{A B }) $ for positive semidefinite matrices $A,B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

Let $A,B$ be two real positive semidefinite matrices of same size. Denote the trace operator by tr. We define the square root of a positive semidefinite matrix $A$ by the unique matrix $\sqrt A$ such that $A= \sqrt A ^\top \sqrt A$.

> Why is $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A})= \text{tr}(\sqrt{A B}) $ true ?

Is $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A + \text{Id}})=\text{tr}(\sqrt{A B + \text{Id} }) $ also true, where Id is the identity matrix of same size?

Comment: Your description of the matrix square root isn't correct.  A positive semidefinite matrix $A$ will have a unique symmetric and positive definite square root such that $A=\sqrt{A} \sqrt{A}$.  It can have lots of other square roots that aren't symmetric or aren't positive semidefinite.

Comment: $AB$ is not symmetric in general so what do you mean by $\sqrt{AB}$?

Comment: @W Should that perhaps be $\sqrt{A} \sqrt{B}$? Note that we don't have $\sqrt{AB} = \sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$ with matrices in the way that we do with numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}$ and $AB$ are similar matrices, since
$AB = \sqrt{A} (\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}) \sqrt{A}^{-1}$.  So one square root
of $AB$ (presumably the one you want) is
$\sqrt{A} \sqrt{\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}} \sqrt{A}^{-1}$.  By similarity it has the same eigenvalues,
and thus the same trace, as $\sqrt{\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}}$.

In the same way, one square root of $AB + I$ is
$ \sqrt{A} \sqrt{\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A} + I} \sqrt{A}^{-1}$, and this has the same trace
as $\sqrt{\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}+I}$.