# Prove $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A})\leq 1$,where both $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, and $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(B)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite, quantum-information

> How can I prove tr$\left(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A}\right)\leq 1$, where both $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite,and $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(B)=1$.

The background of $\text{tr}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A}\right)$ is a concept in quantum information called the **fidelity** of quantum states. For two quantum state $\rho$ and $\sigma$,where $\text{tr}(\rho)=\text{tr}(\sigma)=1,\rho ,\sigma\succeq 0$,$F(\rho,\sigma)=\text{tr}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt \rho \sigma \sqrt \rho}\right)$ is defined as their fidelity,and is used to denote their distance in the Hilbert space.See [Quantum computation and quantum information](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) Chapter 9 for more details.

Now back to the problem. It is not hard under some special cases,like $AB=BA$ so they can have the same set of eigenvector. What about some general cases?

Also these two problems are relevant: [Why is $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A})=\text{tr}(\sqrt{A B }) $ for positive semidefinite matrices $A,B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782129/) and [Prove that if A and B are positive semidefinite, then 0≤tr(AB)≤tr(A)tr(B)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531196/).

But I think there are some flaws in the answer under the post [Why is $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A})=\text{tr}(\sqrt{A B }) $ for positive semidefinite matrices $A,B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782129/) because $\text{det}(A)$ can be 0, so $\sqrt{(A)}^{-1}$ may not exist.

Comment: Actually $(AB)^{1/2}$ showing up in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782129/why-is-tr-sqrt-sqrt-a-b-sqrt-a-tr-sqrta-b-for-a-b-positive-semide does not make sense if $A$ and $B$ do not commute.

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090403/trace-norm-and-bures-distance/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a positive semidefinite matrix $C$ the absolute value $|C|$ is defined as $|C|=(C^*C)^{1/2}.$ Moreover by the polar decomposition there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $C=U|C|$ and consequently $U^*C=|C|.$ In our case for $C=B^{1/2}A^{1/2} $ we have
$$(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}=|B^{1/2}A^{1/2}|$$
Thus $$U^*B^{1/2}A^{1/2}=|B^{1/2}A^{1/2}|$$ for a unitary matrix $U.$ Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^d$ be an orthonormal basis and $f_n=Ue_n.$ Then $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^d$ is an orthonormal basis and
$$ \displaylines{{\rm tr}\, |B^{1/2}A^{1/2}|={\rm tr}\, [U^*B^{1/2}A^{1/2}]=\sum_{n=1}^d \langle U^*B^{1/2}A^{1/2}e_n,e_n\rangle \\ =\sum_{n=1}^d \langle A^{1/2}e_n,B^{1/2}Ue_n\rangle  =
\sum_{n=1}^d \langle A^{1/2}e_n,B^{1/2}f_n\rangle}$$
Thus by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied twice we get
$$\displaylines{{\rm tr}\, |B^{1/2}A^{1/2}|\le \sum_{n=1}^d \| A^{1/2}e_n\|\|B^{1/2}f_n\| \\  \le\left (\sum_{n=1}^d\| A^{1/2}e_n\|^2\right )^{1/2} \left (\sum_{n=1}^d\| B^{1/2}f_n\|^2\right )^{1/2} \\ =({\rm tr}\,A)^{1/2}({\rm tr}\,B)^{1/2}= 1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ryszard's answer, the identity $(\rho^{1/2}\sigma\rho^{1/2})^{1/2}=|\sigma^{1/2}\rho^{1/2}|$ shows that the fidelity can be expressed via the [trace norm](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/trace-norm):
$$
F(\rho,\sigma)=\operatorname{tr}\big(|\sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\rho} |\big)=\|\sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\rho}\|_1
$$
This insight enables a simple proof of the statement in question, *assuming* one is familiar with matrix norms and some of their basic properties:
One can always upper bound the trace norm of a product $\|AB\|_1$ by the product of the [Hilbert-Schmidt norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator#Space_of_Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operators) $\|A\|_2\|B\|_2$ (this is a special case of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm#Properties)) which lets us compute
$$
F(\rho,\sigma)=\|\sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\rho}\|_1\leq \|\sqrt{\sigma}\|_2\|\sqrt{\rho}\|_2=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\sigma})}\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\rho}\sqrt{\rho})}=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(\sigma)\operatorname{tr}(\rho)}=1\,.
$$
In my opinion this proof also illustrates nicely how the assumptions on $\rho$ and $\sigma$ (positive & unit trace) come into play.

Comment: This approach is quite enlightening.