# prove that ${\rm tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt{AA^T}BB^T\sqrt{AA^T}})={\rm tr}(\sqrt{B^TAA^TB})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, quantum-information

Suppose $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, prove that ${\rm tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt{AA^T}BB^T\sqrt{AA^T}})={\rm tr}(\sqrt{B^TAA^TB})$.

The form of LHS comes from fidelity in quantum information (see this [Prove $\text{tr}(\sqrt{\sqrt A B \sqrt A})\leq 1$,where both $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, and $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(B)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531930/) for details). I try to use the same trick (polar decomposition) in the above link, that is there exists unitary $U$ such that $U\sqrt{\sqrt{AA^T}BB^T\sqrt{AA^T}}=\sqrt{AA^T}B$ but no further ideas.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that for $m\times m$ matrices $X$, $Y$ the products $(XY)$ and $(YX)$ have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: @user8675309 Yes , I know that

Comment: Then why not let $X:=\sqrt{AA^T}B$ and $Y:= B^T\sqrt{AA^T}$. Since $(XY)$ and $(YX)$ have the same (real non-negative) eigenvalues their square roots have the same eigenvalue so  $\text{trace}\big((XY)^\frac{1}{2}\big) =\text{trace}\big((YX)^\frac{1}{2}\big)$

Comment: @user8675309 You are right, and the answer below is essentially the same.

Comment: My point was that you can do this directly without taking a detour through polar decomposition and certainly no "trick" is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $|A|$ denote $\sqrt{AA^T}$. Then this statement can be written as
$$
{\rm tr}(\sqrt{|A|BB^T|A|})={\rm tr}(\sqrt{B^TAA^TB})
$$
Now, we can use polar decomposition to note that $A = |A| U$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$. It follows that the left-hand-side can be written as
$$
{\rm tr}(\sqrt{B^T(|A|U)(|A|U)^TB}) = 
{\rm tr}(\sqrt{B^T|A|UU^T|A|B}) = 
{\rm tr}(\sqrt{B^T|A||A|B})
$$

Now, writing $P = B^T|A|$, the left-hand side can br written as ${\rm tr}(\sqrt{P^TP})$ and the altered right-hand side can be written as $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{PP^T})$. Both sums are simply equal to the sum of the singular values of $P$, so the two sides are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{CC^T})$ equals the sum of the singular values of $C$, while $\operatorname{tr}(CC^T)$ the sum of the squares of the same singular values, and the same holds switching $C$ and $C^T$. Thus $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{CC^T})=\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{C^T C})$.

Now observe that the statement is equivalent to the above, with $C=\sqrt{AA^T} B$.